# localhost LDAP URL is not view in the LDAP Browser

Tags: ldap

I'm new for ldap, so please guide me to fix the below issue

Here I using apache directory studio for creating the ldap connection. Once I created the LDAP connection it create Root DSE directory below the directory we have ou=system->ou=user folder below the ou=user I have created 3 users.

```
LDAP URL: ldap://localhost:10389
```

Now I trying to fetch all the users using ldap url in softerra LDAP Administrator, it fetch all the folder except ou=user.
If i try another ldap url  (`ldap://db.debian.org:389` ) it will fetch all records.

Kindly help me to solve this problem

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you haven't created or populated your directory.  In ApacheDS the OUs directly under the Root DSE are for internal server use and not for use as a repository of domain users.

To create something that resembles your example of db.debian.org you would:

- Create a new partition using your domain information (dc=yourdomain,dc=com)
- Right click on the domain in the browser and add an OU for users and then add your users to that new OU